# How do I duplicate row lables in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have created a Pivot Table to display my data filtered according to multiple rows.  However, the output appears as follows:

```
Label1
        Label2
                Label3-1
                Label3-2
                Label3-3

etc...
```

Is there an option to allow me to duplicate these row labels rather than blank them out?  I would like the above to appear more like a data pull from a database like the following:

```
Label1  Label2  Label3-1
Label1  Label2  Label3-2
Label1  Label2  Label3-3

etc...
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in excel 2010,

- Go to Pivot table tools \ Design \ Report layout and choose the Show in Tabular Form option, then
- Go to Pivot table tools \ Design \ Report layout and choose the Repeat all item labels options

Comment: I'm sorry.  I should have stated that I'm using Excel 2007.